# Regression with non-frequent variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a dataset in which I am regressing an output variable which changes daily to 4 independent variables. 3 of these variables changes on a daily frequency, but the other one changes on a quarterly basis. How should I go about such a regression task? Should I take daily data and keep that one variable constant for a quarter or should I do quarterly regression. Is there another way to handle such data?

Comment: It is measured only on a quarterly basis

Comment: I'm taking about GDP growth rate